# Find usage result in Intellij in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

In Windows I used to get a dropdown list when I do 'Ctrl + Alt + F7' (find usage) in Intellij IDE. However in Ubuntu same action gives me a pane with tree view.
How can I configure Intellij in Ubuntu to get a drop down list for find usage action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using a different keymap, please double check that **Show Usages** action is what you are invoking, and not **Find Usages**:

[image: Show Usages]